# Social media Icons transparency issue

Tags: html, css

Hey I have some social media Icons on my webpage and I want it so that at default it is has a white border, transparent background, and white logo. Then on hover have that switch so you get a white border, white background and transparent logo. But It seems that since the logo is transparent on hover, all you see is a white circle. How can I make it so that the transparent logo (i.e. the f in facebook) is still view-able on hover.[This page has what I'm going for](http://www.cynthiabettencourt.com/thecollection/) (scroll down to bottom) I've included a jsfiddle of what I have so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/p0sjxqht/

HTML:

```
<h2>Style Social Media Buttons</h2>


<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest"></a>
```

CSS:

```
body{
background-color: #333;

}
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

.fa:hover {
background: white;
color:transparent;
}

.fa {
border:solid;
border-width:3px;
border-color:white;
background: transparent;
color: white;
}
```

Comment: On the linked site, the icons turn black on mouseover, not transparent. Maybe try that?

Comment: the logos on the example site are not 'transparent' on hover, they just have a dark `color` defined on hover that compliments what's in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Use as color the same color as your background:

```
.fa:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #333;
}
```

Comment: In my actual webpage there is an image as a background rather than a solid color, so how do I make it work for that?

Comment: I think you are looking for this kind of effect when hover: http://nimbupani.com/using-background-clip-for-text-with-css-fallback.html
The problem is that you can't use it in the link components because you are setting the background-color to white, so any transparency applied to text will show the white background.

Answer (score 0):

Just add color inheriting from parent node

```
.fa:hover {
    background: white;
    color:inherit;
}
```

and finally add parent div color as page background is

Comment: In my actual page I have an image as the background, so this doesn't workout. What do i do?

Comment: It doesnt matter, just set parent color as you wish :)

Comment: Where would I set the parent color? I mean what is the parent because this isn't nested? Sorry I'm very new

Comment: In your example, the parent is body tag :) sorry for late reply